# Can we handle Exception and response in the same test case in Spock functional spec

Tags: groovy, spock

My Foo service will return response when the data are available. Foo service doesn't receive data from downstream then it will return 404. Below test-case working fine when receiving 404. When
Foo Service return the data below test-case failed

> *Expected exception of type 'groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException',
> but no exception was thrown*

I want to handle both scenarios in same test case.

```
def "check foo service in real time"() {
    setup:
    String path = "/v1/foo"
    when:
    HttpResponseDecorator response = httpGet(path)
    then:
    HttpResponseException e = thrown()
    if(response){
        assert response.data =="bar"
    }else {
        assert e.statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like 2 separate tests?

Comment: I agree with Tim. You have two distinct and clearly different cases. Why mix them up in a single test? Writing concise tests is important. But brevity for brevity's sake at the expense of readability, maintainability and clear behavioral specifications (which is what Spock tests ought to be) is an anti-pattern. Do yourself and your fellow developers a favour and implement the single responsibility principle along other clean code best practices not just in your application code but also in your tests. Good luck! :-)